# "Doblado" y "pudor"

Tags: historia, sustantivos, arcaísmos

Me fascinan los usos menos conocidos de *doblado* y *pudor*, ambas en el Diccionario de la Real Academia Española:

> [**doblado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E2BYhia)
>
> 6. m. Accidente que acometía a los limpiadores de letrinas, cuando el tufo que se levantaba de estas los dejaba sin sentido.
>
> [**pudor**<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UZQokxM)
>
> 1. m. desus. Mal olor, hedor.

Si aparecen en el DLE es porque existe algún documento escrito que las avale. Pero siendo voces en desuso, y muy posiblemente ya infrecuentes en su época, me ha sido imposible dar con muestras de su empleo.

Al ambas contar con otros significados de empleo corriente, el CREA y del CORDE dan resultados muy abultados o que no tienen relación con mi búsqueda.

Con respecto a “doblado”, pese a no haberme sido posible encontrarlo aplicado, el siglo XIX cuanta con múltiples salidas en otros diccionarios, todas muy similares:

- El Nuevo diccionario de la lengua castellana que comprende la última edición íntegra, muy rectificada y mejorada, del publicado por La Academia Española (Salvá, 1846)

  > Accidente que acomete á los mozos de la limpieza, cuando limpian una letrina, así que empiezan á revolver la porquería, y los deja tendidos como difuntos.
- Diccionario enciclopédico-mejicano del idioma español (Busto, 1884)

  > Med. especie de asfixia que suele acometer á los que se dedican a limpiar letrinas.
- Diccionario popular universal de la lengua española: artes, biografía, ciencias, historia, geografía, literatura y mitología (de Ramón, 1887):

  > Accidente que suele acometer á los que limpian una letrina, al empezar á revolver la porquería, que es una especie de asfixia.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.SE]! La pregunta parece interesante, pero tal y como está redactada es difícil de entender y seguir en ese "tocho" sin párrafos. Te animamos a que la [edit]es y mejores título y cuerpo del post para dejar más claro lo que se pregunta. Puedes consultar la documentación sobre cómo hacer buenas preguntas en [ask]. Recuerda que es buena idea hacer un post por pregunta, no un único post para varias preguntas. También puedes darte una vuelta por el [tour] para más información sobre la filosofía del sitio. Bienvenido de nuevo, ¡esperamos más contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: coincido plenamente con @Diego y, tras darle algunos toques de formato, observo que la pregunta carece de pregunta en sí: ¿cuál es tu duda exactamente? A todo esto, ¡bienvenido al sitio!

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo que la duda es que le gustaría encontrar textos que acrediten que las palabras "doblado" y "pudor" se usaron con los significados recogidos.

Comment: Sigo pensando que puede ser buena idea (si charlie está en lo cierto sobre de qué va la pregunta) en dividirlo en dos (una vez el OP lo aclare/confirme). Aunque ambos términos estén muy relacionados, es posible que encontremos información para uno pero no para el otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus prontos comentarios y ayudas.

Comment: Yendo por partes. Mi consulta fue perfectamente escrita, puntuada y diagramada en Word. Y ese supuesto “tocho” ha aparecido por defecto del servicio. Es la primera vez que escribo en un sitio de este tipo (y de otro). No controlo los intríngulis del buen bloguero.

Comment: Como sea, pienso que hay dos puntos más o menos claros, en vista de las respuestas de administradores y usuarios: si bien son dos palabras, apuntan, hipotéticamente, a una misma cuestión, por lo que sería absurdo y desgastador separarlas; como bien señala Charlie solo necesito ejemplos que confirmen su uso (y por tanto su realidad viva en la lengua), ya que las definiciones parecen azas claras.

Comment: Por último, no sé si debo definirlo en las configuraciones, pero no me han llegado las notificaciones de las respuestas. Si es el caso, desconozco cómo se hace.

Answer (score 6):

Sobre ***pudor***: es palabra latina que etimológicamente nunca ha significado otra cosa que "vergüenza", como atestiguan casi todos los diccionarios de antes de mitad del s. XIX. No es hasta el SALVÁ de 1846 que aparece esta otra acepción, y además nos da una pista de su origen:

[image]

> **PUDOR**. [...] ant. HEDOR. *Putor*.

Ya entonces se recogía como acepción antigua, y parece que la explica como proveniente del latín *[putor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putor#Latin)* (significado que [ya recogía Nebrija](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=putor&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000)) pero alterando la pronunciación, imagino que tras un proceso natural de [debilitación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debilitamiento) `/t/` > `/d/`, aunque también podría ser por el parecido con "pudrir".
La verdad es que cuadra bastante, sin embargo apenas ningún otro diccionario del XIX (ni del XX, ya que estamos) recoge esa acepción.

El ZEROLO de 1895 incluye otras dos palabras relacionadas con ella:

[image]

Sin embargo no reconoce la propia *pudor* como "hedor", y ningún otro diccionario posterior recoge tampoco estas nuevas palabras con ese significado.

En cuanto al *Diccionario* de la RAE, **no es hasta 1970 que se incluye en el DLE la acepción de marras**:

[image]

Por otra parte y como curiosidad, he incluido en el recorte el *pudio* que salía en ZEROLO, pero solo para mostrar que según el DLE se refiere única y exclusivamente a un tipo de pino (cosa que la RAE venía afirmando desde la edición de 1899, contemporánea con aquel).

La verdad es que no comprendo la inclusión de esta acepción de **pudor** en esta edición: un uso testimonial de una palabra latina mal pronunciada, que ya 125 años antes se reconocía como uso anticuado y que no se encuentra en ninguna obra escrita en español (¡ni siquiera diccionarios!) en los últimos cinco siglos... ¯\_(ヅ)_/¯

Pero bueno, **ya que pides usos** (o, al menos, entiendo que eso es lo que pides; te recomiendo que atiendas a los comentarios de los moderadores), [**en el CORDE hay varios**](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=pudor&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=1600&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), aunque *todos* (menos uno, que parece transcripción de un texto más antiguo) anteriores al s. XVI.
Es como si la publicación del diccionario de Nebrija en 1495, asociando *pudor* a *vergüenza* y *putor* a *olor malo*, hubiese hecho recapacitar a los escribientes y hubiesen dejado de usarla con ese sentido.

---

En cuanto a **doblado**, veo que ya tienes localizada la aparición en diccionarios, y que son ejemplos lo que te faltan. Es cierto que en este caso es más complicado hallarlos, pues es una palabra mucho más común que *pudor*. Algunos consejos para encontrar ejemplos:

- **Buscar la palabra en el [Fichero de la RAE](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html)** si no lo has hecho ya. En estas fichas se suele indicar la obra en la que se ha encontrado la palabra registrada, y eso te puede ayudar a localizar ejemplos. (Aviso: las primeras cien fichas te las puedes saltar, pues ya las he revisado yo y ninguna corresponde al significado que comentas.)
- **Usar el [operador DIST en el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/ayuda_c.htm#_Toc30228235)** para encontrar usos de *doblado* que aparezcan cerca de otras palabras relacionadas con ese significado, como *letrina*, *asfixia* o quizá *olor*.
- **Buscar en [Google Books](https://books.google.es)**, quizá tengas más suerte.

**EDITO**: He encontrado la [ficha con la definición que comentas](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_D/LETRA_D_PDF/DOBLADO/00000390.pdf) [PDF] aunque, lamentablemente, no hace referencia a ninguna obra en concreto. Pero también he encontrado algunas otras como [esta](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_D/LETRA_D_PDF/DOBLADO/00001518.pdf) y [esta](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_D/LETRA_D_PDF/DOBLADO/00001566.pdf) que recogen usos en el sentido de "enfermo, débil"; o [esta otra](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_D/LETRA_D_PDF/DOBLADO/00001548.pdf) que lo define como "inclinado". En general diría que el uso de "doblado" aplicado a los desmayos de los limpiadores de letrinas, vendría a ser una mezcla de todos estos sentidos, que seguramente se ha perdido ya, aunque hoy en día se sigue diciendo "estar doblado" o "quedarse doblado" cuando a uno le sobreviene un dolor fuerte.

Comment: _Pudor_ es la palabra que se usa en catalán para el mal olor. Por tanto, puede que por proximidad con el castellano se haya añadido en algún momento.

Comment: Es interesante saber que en español existen **las partes pudendas** o sea _las vergüenzas_.  En anatomía hay **el nervio pudendo** que inerva las partes pudendas, y en ingles hay el **pudendum** con la misma etimología.

Comment: Muchas gracias Walen. Muy ilustrada y certera tu respuesta. Por desgracia no llego a dar con ejemplos de "doblado". Me pregunto si pueda ser un caso de una palabra no ya en desuso sino sin uso. Algo así como una arbitraria invención de neólogos. Gracias también Fedorqui y Exaneta.